# How to split a dataframe heaving a list of column values and counts?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV based dataframe

```
name  value
A       5
B       5
C       5
D       1
E       2
F       1
```

and a values count dictionary like this:

```
{
 5: 2,
 1: 1
}
```

How to split original dataframe into two:

```
name  value
A       5
B       5
D       1

name  value
C       5
E       2
F       1
```

So how to split a dataframe heaving a list of column values and counts in pandas?

Comment: This depends on your criteria for splitting. In your example you have even rows split from odd. The obvious answer is to perform arbitrary calculations in python code and just rebuild from there. Perhaps if you could give your split criteria explicitly someone might be able to suggest the pandas code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
def target_indices(df, value_count):
    indices = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for key in value_count:
            if key == row['value'] and value_count[key] > 0:
                indices.append(index)
                value_count[key] -= 1
    return(indices)


df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': [5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1]})

value_count = {5: 2, 1: 1}

indices = target_indices(df, value_count)

df1 = df.iloc[indices]
print(df1)
df2 = df.drop(indices)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  name  value
0    A      5
1    B      5
3    D      1

  name  value
2    C      5
4    E      2
5    F      1
```